# Internal build system error. read the full binlog without getting a BuildFinishedMessage, while the backend process is still running

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I just can't use Unity! Every time when I want to **open my project** I have an error and Unity reccomends me to open project in Safe Mode. When the project's opening is finished (doesn't matter if I open it Safe Mode or not) I can do litteraly NOTHING - there's no objects on the scene, I can't open prefab, etc. There's error in the console `"Internal build system error. read the full binlog without getting a BuildFinishedMessage, while the backend process is still running"`

And when I try to **create a new project** it seems like it's gonna open, but i see [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYXwZ.png). This project appears in the Unity Hub, but when I click on it, there's another [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnDCE.png).

I tried a lot of things, that I saw on the internet, for example: deleting "Library" folder or deleting "Cache" folder. I also tried to reinstall Unity Editor and Hub - nothing happened.

So, StackOverflow is my last hope.

Edit:
Sometimes when I try to open project I can see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYURC.png).

Comment: Important note: I had this issue *without even building* a single time!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me recently.

If it’s a project specific error, try to delete the Library and the Logs folder in your project.
Then restart your PC.
After this, start Unity Hub/Unity as administrator.
For some users this fixed the issue.

But it looks like this is a Unity issue for you. Same for me!
In my case the issue was installing Unity on a secondary hard drive with insufficient file permissions. For some reason windows would always reset my permission overrides and Unity would not be able to read/write from it‘s editor directory.

So the solution was to install Unity on my C:/ drive under C:/users/[USERNAME]/Unity/…
Also try moving the Project to the same Hard Drive as the Unity install.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you missed some modules to install, if you want to build in windows, then except windows support, you also need to install universal windows build support.